# How to save my entire Linux image on a USB stick

Tags: linux, system-restore

I have a question.
I want to save my entire Linux image on a USB drive, so I can restore it when I need to. But what is the best way to do this?

Comment: The software tools and the methods that go with them aren't dependent on the destination target for the resulting image.

Comment: What should I do then? I have never backuped my whole image

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/541008/create-system-imagesteps-to-clone-all-partitions

Comment: Whay is your goal? The easiest way would be to bitcopy the partition to the USB key (or a file on the USB key) possibly using compression and making sure empty space is 0. This is easy to do, transfer and restore, but not self-contained or bootable. Note that there is no "best way" - there are lots of variants of lots of equally good ways depending on your goals.  The closer you get to a generic bootable USB Image the harder the process, not all able to result in something that can be used to create a clone if the original system.

Comment: First:
`telinit 1`

Uncompressed Bit copy? use **dd**
Compressed bit copy?

`dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -c | /mnt/file.image`

Easier to use? (never tried: **clonezilla**)

I prefer **rsync**. I just copy my entire system (live aka: bad practice) and restore the files if needed.

In practice it's pain to restore the *system* but who cares about the system? I want the user files. I rarely restore my system. Once in 10 years maybe :-) I like to keep /etc folder for my settings.

So check your case and act accordingly.